# Copy from AWS EC2 to EFS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

How can I copy files in the aws session manager from my ec2 instance to efs without using datasync?

Thanks.

I tried using scp to copy the files and it errors out.  I would use ssh but I do not have the permissions to ssh from my local machine.  Can I use AWS-copy?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount the EFS volume to the EC2 instance. You can't copy anything to EFS without first mounting the EFS volume. Once EFS is mounted it would show up in the EC2 file system and you could copy to it using a regular `cp` command, targeting the path the EFS volume is mounted to.